# How can I give dynamic timeperiod to periodic task in django celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat, periodic-task

I have a task to send remind  mails to my users before one hour of specific occasion. How can I set the time of periodic  task ?

```
`code`
@periodic_task( ? )
def auto_email():
    subject = "Exam"
    date_time = datetime.now()
    body = ""
    to = []
    after_hour_time = date_time +  timedelta(minutes=60)
    student_qs = Student.objects.filter(date_time = after_hour_time)
    for obj in student_qs :
       to.append(obj.email)     
    send_mail(subject, body, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,to)
```

Thanks

Comment: If it is connected to a **specific** occasion, it is not periodic. Can't you schedule the task whenever you learn about the occasion?

Comment: I have a datetime  of every  occasion. Have to  send mail according to that time (only to that users those who are related with occasion). I think this  is  possible  with periodic.

Comment: I'd just use a common [`Task`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html) and call `apply_async` with the appropriate [`eta`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown) parameter in relation to your occasion. You can to that e.g. when you create the occasion.

Comment: hey I have to do it automatically, There is no button to call that task. How I  will call to simple task  automatic ?

Comment: What is this specific occasion? Does it create any objects? Do you have control of the code that send mails?

Comment: NO It will not create any object. Its like reminder mail to all students that you have a exam after one hour.(I am sending mail as school teacher)

Comment: When/or how you are sending this mail, do you do it in python code? If so provide it

Comment: `code`@periodic_task( ................ )
def auto_remind_email():
 subject = "Exam"
 date_time = datetime.now()
 present_date = date_time.date() 
 body = ""
 to = ["........all the email......."]
 after_hour_time = date_time.time() +  timedelta(minutes=60)
 send_mail(subject, body, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,to)

Comment: I am sending mail  before 60 mint of exam time. and using simple send_mail method of python

Comment: Add it to post not comment))

Comment: I meant code of your "specific occasion"

Comment: Occasion is just a simple date in model, I update the code in qus.